# Junit5 en aplicación web

Tags: java, web, junit

Necesito crear alguna aplicación web para definir una serie de pruebas JUnit, y que al subir una clase a dicha página se le proporcione una puntuación, sin que el usuario vea el código de los tests.

Se que existe porque en la universidad utilizamos algo parecido, pero no recuerdo el nombre.

¿Alguien conoce algún repositorio, web o aplicación parecida?